# Considering makecontext() what is uc_stack.ss_size good for?

Tags: c++, ucontext

Prior to calling `makecontext` why do we need to set the stack size `ss_size`?

I just had an unit test case for `makecontext/swapcontext` snippet and it failed with `SIGSEGV`. What happened was that stack size was too small and unrelated memory (happened to be some unique pointers) got corrupted and reported segfault. So the segfault was on these unrelated pointers, I could have had e.g. some string and then the memory corruption would have been unnoticed.

I would have expected that `SIGSEGV` is beeing raised immediately when stack size `ss_size` does not suffice, but
considering the memory corruption described above, I conclude its impossible to recover from `SIGSEGV` here. That brings me back to the question, why do we need to set the stack size then in first place, when it is not being used to signal overflows? What is it used for?

---

EDIT:

Well it's all about [makecontext(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/makecontext.3.html). These functions are still being used for green threads, coroutines etc. There is just no real replacement for them considering these tasks (in my opinion) also not in c++.

`ss_size` defined in [sigaltstack(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaltstack.2.html) is being needed for `uc_stack` in `ucontext_t` defined in [getcontext(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcontext.3.html).

Following a [minimal verifiable example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gXoXiBEQ3aNqmLQl) that shows the memory corruption, by "painting" the memory, described above.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

ucontext_t caller, callee;
void cb(void){
    //paint stack with 2
    char tmp[7000];
    std::memset(tmp,2,7000);
    //note stack size specified 6k bytes in size
    //this should not be allowed.
    //furthermore there is not even some signal raised here
    //i expected raised SIGSEGV when this call stack exceeds ss_size
    //it makes ss_size useless no?
}
int main(){
    //
    std::memset(&caller,0,sizeof(caller));
    std::memset(&callee,0,sizeof(callee));

    //create stack and paint 0
    std::unique_ptr<std::byte[]> stack(new std::byte[10000]());
    std::memset(stack.get(),0,10000);//paint stack 0

    //make context
    //note stack specified to [2000,8000)
    //that means [0,2000) and [8000,10000) should not be touched
    if(getcontext(&callee) == -1) {std::cout << errno << ":" << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl; return 1;}
    callee.uc_link = &caller;
    callee.uc_stack.ss_sp = stack.get()+2000;
    callee.uc_stack.ss_size = 6000; //what is this line good for, what is it guarding?
    makecontext(&callee,cb,0);

    //swap to callee
    if(swapcontext(&caller,&callee) == -1) {std::cout << errno << ":" << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl; return 1;}

    //print color - should be 0
    //if 2 then memory corrupted by callee
    std::cout << int(stack[996]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << int(stack[997]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << int(stack[998]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << int(stack[999]) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Once again what I don't understand is why we need to set the stack size `ss_size`, because it looks like that it is not being used to guard against memory corruption or anything else. It looks like it is just there to be there but without any use. But I can't believe that it has no use. So what is it "guarding" / good for?

Well, I don't want to bring more confusion into this. The goal is to get away from a fixed size function call stack by either being able to recover by installing `SIGSEGV` signal handler, but this looks like mission impossible due to this memory corruption; or to have a growable stack e.g. using [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) with `MAP_GROWSDOWN` flag, but this looks [broken](https://lwn.net/Articles/294001/) and therefore not an option.

Comment: What is `ss_size` and how do you set it? Please show the code. I see it's used for [signal stack](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signal-Stack.html)? Why do you need to use it when using systemV api? Why do you use such an old api anyway?

Comment: @KamilCuk I've updated the question. Hope this clears things up.

Comment: `//note stack size specified 6k bytes in size
    //this should not be allowed.` - SIGSEGV happening and _expecting_ SIGSEGV to happen are different things. You cannot expect SIGSEGV to happen if you write outside allowed memory, there may just happen to be a valid address inside your process space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> callee.uc_stack.ss_size = 6000; // what is this line good for, what is it guarding?

This line set's the stack size (as you could read in [man sigalstack](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaltstack.2.html)). From reading [makecontext from glibc](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/makecontext.c#L68) the `ss_size` is used for determining end of stack, where glibc [setups the stack](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/makecontext.c#L113) of the new context. Because stack on some machine "grows toward numerically lower addresses" (like it does on [x86 architecture](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/04/where-the-top-of-the-stack-is-on-x86/) and [wiki x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Addressing_modes)) the `makecontext` needs/wants to place it data on the end of the stack. So it needs to determinate the end of stack and this is what `ss_size` is used for.

Setting `ss_size` to any value *does not* mean that overflowing the stack size will issue a operating system signal to your process that notifies that your process tried to access restricted memory area. The implementation of `*context` isn't (and, well, shouldn't be) designed to make the address `ss_sp + ss_size (+ 1)` as kernel protected memory, so that writing to that address will trigger segmentation fault. This is still all normal variables. As always with writing to an unknown memory location and for example overflowing arrays, the invalid address *may just happen to be* inside your process address space, so according to the kernel the process will be writing inside it's address space and everything is fine. As you do here - your `cb` function writes inside `new std::byte[10000]` memory, from the kernel perspective there is nothing wrong with that.

You most probably could allocate `new std::byte[6000]` and run your process under valgrind or gdb or other tools to inspect malicious writes.

Comment: SMH! Looking at my question after your answer I should have been able to answer the need of the stack size myself at the latest after the wrong painting at the numerically LOWER addresses. [makecontext from glibc](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/makecontext.c#L68) gives great insight. The little sketch and the comments about the arguments are gold.